# unlink(assets/images/profile/1649308242.png): No such file or directory

Tags: laravel

error after deploy my laravel app to server
my code works fine on my loacal machine but after upload it to the server i got this error

```
if($this->newimage)
        {
            if($this->image)
            {
                unlink('assets/images/profile/'.$this->image);
            }
            $imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp . '.' . $this->newimage->extension();
            $this->newimage->storeAs('profile',$imageName);
            $user->profile->image = $imageName;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The address of a **file** should be an **absolute path**. I don't know where is your `assets` directory but in the case of being in your Laravel app root, this would be the solution:

```
unlink(base_path('assets/images/profile/'.$this->image));
```

Comment: my assets folder in public html on the live server public_html/assets the error unlink(/home/u828321754/domains/body-vivid.com/public_html/assets/images/profile/1649327677.png): No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

you can set your storage directory instead of public

```
 $storePath = storage_path('app/public/'.$this->image); 
 if (file_exists($storePath)) {
     Storage::disk('public')->delete($this->image);
 }
```

Comment: this code is working put still have problem the image updated but after refresh the photo  not showing

Answer (score 0):

use the helper asset('path/to/file')

e.g.

if this is your image path public/assets/images/profile/1649308242.png.

```
unlink(asset('assets/images/profile').'/'.$this->image);
```

Comment: it gives me this error    unlink(): http does not allow unlinking

Comment: attach proper error, you can also try this.

`$image_path = ‘path_to_the_file’
if(File::exists($image_path)) {
     File::delete($image));
}`